# centOS7にphpMyAdminをyumでインストールしたさいのエラー

Tags: centos, phpmyadmin, yum

初歩的な質問なのですが、centOS7にmariaDB,php7,phpMyAdminを導入したいのですが、

```
yum install phpMyAdmin
```

を実行した時に以下のエラーが返ってくるのですが何を修正すれば良いのでしょうか？

```
Error: Package: php-tidy-5.4.16-4.el7.x86_64 (epel)
       Requires: php(zend-abi) = 20100525-64
       Installed: php-common-7.0.9-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (@remi-php70)
           php(zend-abi) = 20151012-64
       Available: php-common-5.4.16-36.el7_1.x86_64 (base)
           php(zend-abi) = 20100525-64
       Available: php-common-5.4.16-36.1.el7_2.1.x86_64 (updates)
           php(zend-abi) = 20100525-64
Error: Package: phpMyAdmin-4.4.15.7-1.el7.noarch (epel)
       Requires: php-zip
       Available: php-common-5.4.16-36.el7_1.x86_64 (base)
           php-zip
       Available: php-common-5.4.16-36.1.el7_2.1.x86_64 (updates)
           php-zip
       Installed: php-common-7.0.9-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (@remi-php70)
           Not found
Error: Package: php-tidy-5.4.16-4.el7.x86_64 (epel)
       Requires: php(api) = 20100412-64
       Installed: php-common-7.0.9-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (@remi-php70)
           php(api) = 20151012-64
       Available: php-common-5.4.16-36.el7_1.x86_64 (base)
           php(api) = 20100412-64
       Available: php-common-5.4.16-36.1.el7_2.1.x86_64 (updates)
           php(api) = 20100412-64
Error: Package: php-bcmath-5.4.16-36.1.el7_2.1.x86_64 (updates)
       Requires: php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.16-36.1.el7_2.1
       Installed: php-common-7.0.9-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (@remi-php70)
           php-common(x86-64) = 7.0.9-1.el7.remi
       Available: php-common-5.4.16-36.el7_1.x86_64 (base)
           php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.16-36.el7_1
       Available: php-common-5.4.16-36.1.el7_2.1.x86_64 (updates)
           php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.16-36.1.el7_2.1
```

アドバイスをいただけると助かります。よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 2):

すでに remi-php70 リポジトリの php-common がインストールされているようです。
remi-php70 リポジトリが無効(デフォルト)のまま phpMyAdmin をインストールしようとして、phpMyAdmin に必要な PHP 関連パッケージのバージョンが、インストール済みの php-common と競合するためエラーとなっています。

remi-php70 リポジトリを有効にしてインストールしてみてください。

```
# yum --enablerepo=remi-php70 install phpMyAdmin
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。うまくインストールできました。