# CentOS 7, PHP 7.1.7, MariaDB 10.2.7 にphpMyAdminをyumでインストールした際のエラー

Tags: php, centos, phpmyadmin, mariadb

環境：CentOS 7, PHP 7.1.7, MariaDB 10.2.7

この環境にphpMyAdminをインストールしようとしたところ、
以下のエラーで進められず困っております。

```
$ sudo yum install phpMyAdmin
```

下記のエラーがでたので、

[centOS7にphpMyAdminをyumでインストールしたさいのエラー](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/28071/centos7%E3%81%ABphpmyadmin%E3%82%92yum%E3%81%A7%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AB%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E3%81%95%E3%81%84%E3%81%AE%E3%82%A8%E3%83%A9%E3%83%BC)

こちらのアドバイスを参考に

```
$ sudo yum --enablerepo=remi-php71 install phpMyAdmin
```

を試してみたのですが、エラーは変わりませんでした。

```
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: php-tidy-5.4.16-7.el7.x86_64 (epel)
       Requires: php(api) = 20100412-64
       Installed: php-common-7.1.7-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (@remi-php71)
           php(api) = 20160303-64
       Available: php-common-5.4.16-42.el7.x86_64 (base)
           php(api) = 20100412-64
       Available: php-common-7.1.6-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php71)
           php(api) = 20160303-64
Error: Package: php-tidy-5.4.16-7.el7.x86_64 (epel)
       Requires: php(zend-abi) = 20100525-64
       Installed: php-common-7.1.7-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (@remi-php71)
           php(zend-abi) = 20160303-64
       Available: php-common-5.4.16-42.el7.x86_64 (base)
           php(zend-abi) = 20100525-64
       Available: php-common-7.1.6-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php71)
           php(zend-abi) = 20160303-64
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: 自己解決できました。見て検討頂いた方、ありがとうございました。
解決策を記載しておきます。
**remi-php71** を見に行って欲しいのがうまく行ってなかったので、
それを解決する方法を探したところ、

/etc/yum.repos.d/remi.repo

このファイルの中に、

`priority = 1`

を追記することで、優先的に71を見に行ってくれるようになりました。
結果、インストールは無事完了致しました。
ありがとうございました。

参考：[http://higherhope.net/?p=2731]

Comment: お疲れ様でした。もしよろしければ[自己回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)して頂けませんでしょうか？

Comment: 失礼致しました。回答を追記しました。宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: いえいえ、もし可能であればという程度のつもりでした。ありがとうございます！

Answer (score 2):

自己解決できました。
見て検討頂いた方、ありがとうございました。
解決策を記載しておきます。
remi-php71 を見に行って欲しいのがうまく行ってなかったので、 
それを解決する方法を探したところ、

/etc/yum.repos.d/remi-php71.repo

このファイルの中に、

```
priority = 1
```

こんな感じに。

```
[remi-php71]
name=Remi's PHP 7.1 RPM repository for Enterprise Linux 7 - $basearch
#baseurl=http://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/7/php71/$basearch/
#mirrorlist=https://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/7/php71/httpsmirror
mirrorlist=http://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/7/php71/mirror
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-remi
priority=1
```

※以下略

を追記することで、優先的に71を見に行ってくれるようになりました。
結果、インストールは無事完了致しました。

参考：[http://higherhope.net/?p=2731](http://higherhope.net/?p=2731])